# How to apply filter inside curly brackets in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

How to write any filter inside {{}} curly brackets.

```
<span>{{viewController.viewModel.name == '' ? 'abcd' | upper : viewController.viewModel.name}}</span>
```

At here upper is filter and anykind of custom filter. I don't want to use ng-if twice for this only. This one is not working. It's gives error of filter

please suggest me good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I think the filter needs to come after the expression, eg

```
<span>{{viewController.viewModel.name == '' ? 'abcd' : viewController.viewModel.name | upper}}</span>
```